# Running into troubles with data path (os.path.isdir(path) returning false when it exists) using FB XLM

Tags: directory, path, bert-language-model, language-model

I'm trying to run an evaluation on FB's Transcoder (https://github.com/facebookresearch/TransCoder) which implements FB's XLM (cross language model): https://github.com/facebookresearch/XLM#iii-applications-supervised--unsupervised-mt

I have everything configured and follow the instructions as in the github page where I run the validation/test set unzip them and place them into a specific directory: `/home/username/TransCoder/data/bpe.cpp-java-python.with_comments/XLM-cpp-java-python-with-comments-functions-sa-cl-split-test`.
When I run the following command that is in the **run an evaluation** section:

```
python XLM/train.py 
--n_heads 8 
--bt_steps 'python_sa-cpp_sa-python_sa,cpp_sa-python_sa-cpp_sa,java_sa-cpp_sa-java_sa,cpp_sa-java_sa-cpp_sa,python_sa-java_sa-python_sa,java_sa-python_sa-java_sa' # The evaluator will use this parameter to infer the languages to test on 
--max_vocab '-1'  
--word_blank '0.1' 
--n_layers 6  
--generate_hypothesis true 
--max_len 512 
--bptt 256  
--fp16 true 
--share_inout_emb true 
--tokens_per_batch 6000 
--has_sentences_ids true 
--eval_bleu true  
--split_data false  
--data_path '/home/salzubi/TransCoder/data/bpe.cpp-java-python.with_comments/XLM-cpp-java-python-with-comments-functions-sa-cl-split-test'  
--eval_computation true 
--batch_size 32 
--reload_model 'model_1.pth,model_1.pth'  
--amp 2  
--max_batch_size 128 
--ae_steps 'cpp_sa,python_sa,java_sa' 
--emb_dim 1024 
--eval_only True 
--beam_size 10 
--retry_mistmatching_types 1 
--dump_path '/tmp/' 
--exp_name='eval_final_model_wc_30' 
--lgs 'cpp_sa-java_sa-python_sa' 
--encoder_only=False
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XLM/train.py", line 337, in <module>
    check_data_params(params)
  File "/home/username/TransCoder/XLM/src/data/loader.py", line 246, in check_data_params
    assert os.path.isdir(params.data_path), params.data_path
AssertionError
```

I'm not sure why this is the case?

```
$ python
import os
print(os.path.isdir("/home/username/TransCoder/data/bpe.cpp-java-python.with_comments/XLM-cpp-java-python-with-comments-functions-sa-cl-split-test"))

output:
True
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: even i've got similar issue. posted it in Transcoder Github (https://github.com/facebookresearch/TransCoder/issues/39) please let me know if you've got any lead